# multiple middleware routing not working in laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, routes, middleware

```
Route::middleware(['auth', 'moderator'], ['auth', 'admin'])->group(function() {
    Route::get('/dashboard', function() {
        return view('dashboard');
    });
});
```

I used this but it didn't work for me.

I already done this.

```
'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\Admin::class,
        'moderator' => \App\Http\Middleware\Moderator::class,
```

in kernel.php

In my Moderator middleware,

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if($request->user()->role === 'moderator') {
            return $next($request);
        }
        return redirect('/');
    }
```

In my Admin middleware,

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if($request->user()->role === 'admin') {
            return $next($request);
        }
        return redirect('/');
    }
```

t only checks for the first one like ['auth', 'moderator'] in this one.

Whatever I put in the first one in the routing, it only checks for that, it doesn't check for the second one. What can I do is there any solution?

Comment: `Route::middleware(['auth', 'moderator', 'admin'])`

Comment: Route::middleware(['auth', 'moderator', 'admin'])->get('/dashboard', function() {
    return view('dashboard');
});

Comment: didn't worked for me..

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
`Route::middleware(['auth', 'moderator|admin'])->group(function() {
   Route::get('/dashboard', function() {
       return view('dashboard');
   });
});`
```

may it works ;)